# what is the sum of this geometrical series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

what is the sum of  the series $\sum(1/\sqrt3^{n})$

my answer was $1/(\sqrt3-1)$ while my friend gotten $1/(1-1/\sqrt3)$

and what I thought is that the sum formula $a/(1-r)$ have to be done when $r^{n-1}$, thus our answer is different

Comment: Please always include limits with your summation signs. 
You can do this by typing \sum_{"lower limit"}^{"upper limit"}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the sum begins with $\;n=0\;$ the sum is

$$\frac1{1-\frac1{\sqrt3}}=\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt3-1}$$

If the sum begins with $\;n=1\;$ the sum is then

$$\frac{\frac1{\sqrt3}}{1-\frac1{\sqrt3}}=\frac1{\sqrt3-1}$$

as you can see, it **all** dependes on what index your infinite geometric series begins

Comment: Even an infinite series must start with a single term.

Comment: @mathreadler Apparently so...what's your point, please?

Comment: There is no point, just a joke referring to the old saying "even a long walk must start with a single step".

Comment: @mathreadler Oh, I see...hehe. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For a geometric series the sum of the first $n$ terms is $a_0{1-q^n\over 1-q}$ so when $\|q\|\lt 1$ the sum converges to ${1\over 1-q}$... So assuming we start with $n=0$, your friend is right and the sum is

$${1\over 1-{1\over \sqrt{3}}}={\sqrt{3}\over \sqrt{3}-1}={3+\sqrt{3}\over 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

One may use the classic evaluation

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x},\qquad |x|<1,
> $$

giving, with $\displaystyle x=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac1{\sqrt{3}}}=\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt3-1}.
$$ or
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac1{\sqrt{3}}}-1=\frac1{\sqrt3-1}
$$

Comment: ${1\over 1-{1\over\sqrt{3}}}\neq {1\over\sqrt{3}-1}$

Comment: @marwalix I don't see what you mean, you have $\frac1{1-\frac1{\sqrt{3}}}-1=\frac1{\sqrt3-1}$

Comment: Sorry I had the impression the two results had been interverted. Now they are right

Comment: The typo was corrected before your comment :)

Comment: I am quick with mathjax on my smartphone but not quick enough

Comment: I've never used mathjax with my smartphone, I'm not so skilful ;-)